# Bash variables definition order

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a setting.sh file with this line:

```
HOME="/var/lib/${USER}"
```

Then I have a shell.sh with these lines (in order):

```
. ./settings.sh
USER="test"
```

1. Can I set a $home without first setting $user?
2. If I use a default user in setting.sh and then set it as a new value in shell.sh, will it update the home variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No to both. Statements are executed in order. If you change `$USER` that will not retroactively update `$HOME`. Makefiles have lazy variable expansions, but not shell scripts.

You could reorder the statements:

```
USER="test"
. ./settings.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

Answers to your questions:

```
1. No
2. No
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can ( so $user = "")
2. It will not update your $HOME variable

typical computer programming concepts

```
int a = 5; // a = 5
int c = a; // c = 5
a = 7; // c is still 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this was worth a question. You can easily try this and answer your own question:

```
$ A="B IS ${B}"
$ echo $A
B IS
$ B=FOO
$ echo $B
FOO
$ echo $A
B IS
```

In other words, the right-hand side expression is evaluated on assignment. Which means that answers to both of your questions are no.

What you can do, however, is to perform lazy evaluation. For example:

```
$ A="B IS \${B}"
$ echo $A
B IS ${B}
$ eval echo $A
B IS
$ B=FOO
$ echo $A
B IS ${B}
$ eval echo $A
B IS FOO
$
```

Good Luck!